# pandas .apply of anonymous function unexpectedly returning series of function objects

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, types, apply

While reading the [apply documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), I attempted to perform a similar operation to that demonstrated in this example (pulled directly from the link):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[4, 9]] * 3, columns=['A', 'B'])

>>> df

   A  B
0  4  9
1  4  9
2  4  9 

>>> df.apply(np.sum, axis=0)

A    12
B    27
dtype: int64
```

where the choice of axis=0 indicates that the function is applied to each column, as we can see from the new row indices being the names of the previous columns.

But, something unexpected happened when I applied (what I thought was) the anonymized version of the function, vs. applying the function directly (disclaimer: I know there is no reason to use an anonymous function here. I am just experimenting with what does what to build my intuition).

Here is my function:

```
>>> def my_function(a_column):
        values_in_col = list(set(a_column))
        new_strings_list = ["{}.{}".format(a_column.name,values) for values in values_in_col]
        return new_strings_list
```

and it works how I expected:

```
>>> df

  A B
0 3 4
1 2 4
2 1 9

>>> df.apply(my_function, axis=0)

A ['A.1', 'A.2', 'A.3']
B ["B.4", "B.9"]
```

But if I try to apply it via lambda, I get a series of function objects:

```
>>> df2 = df.apply(lambda x: my_function, axis=0)
>>> df2

A    <function generate_new_col_names at 0x11938ab90>
B    <function generate_new_col_names at 0x11938ab90>
dtype: object

>>> df2[0](df["A"])
['A.1', 'A.2', 'A.3']

>>> type(df2)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

>>> type(df2[1])
<class 'function'>
```

So, a couple of things.

1) What's up with "dtype: object" when the type of df2[#] is not object? I thought that dtype must be coming from pandas and type just coming from python and that that would explain this, [but the conversion doesn't seem to hold](https://pbpython.com/pandas_dtypes.html).

2) Each "x" being passed to lambda in turn should be a column because of my parameter axis=0, right? So why am I getting something different than I would when I plug in each column directly?

```
>>> my_function(df.A)
['A.1', 'A.2', 'A.3']

>>> (lambda x: my_function(x))(df.A)
['A.1', 'A.2', 'A.3']
```

It appears to be spitting out actual functions instead of the evaluated functions-- so where is the input going, then? I tried this experiment and it seemed to be evaluating the function instead of returning a function object:

```
>>> def my_other_func(x): # I'm just doing an external def'n to mirror what happened before
     return x + 1

>>> my_other_func(4)
5

>>> (lambda x: my_other_func(x))(4)
5

>>> test = (lambda x: my_other_func(x))(4)
>>> type(test)
int
```

So it seems that the use of "apply" is involved in my misexpectation of the previous result.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out.

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: my_function, axis=0)
```

yields a series of function objects, but

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: my_function(x), axis=0)
```

yields the desired outcome.